# Compilation error (incompatible types) when using 'byte' primitive type instead of 'int'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, primitive-types

Since my numbers are quite small (between 0 and 13), I've decided that using **byte** instead of **int** could bring a tiny performance improvement. However, I'm getting the following compilation error:

> Error:(87, 31) error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to byte

[image: Compilation error]

Here is the essential part of the Card class constructor, which seems to be just right, requiring bytes for both arguments:

[image: Card class constructor]

This is very strange, and I would like to hear from you what's the reason, am I missing something?

Comment: What would passing `-10` in for either of these parameters mean? You should consider using an enum for each of them instead of a byte.

Comment: @AndyTurner This is more of a conceptual question, rather than actual project implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default type for literal values supplied as literals in that manner is `int`, cast the values to a `byte`. Like,

```
Card card = new Card((byte) 1, (byte) 12);
```

**or** declare local values to hold the arguments (the Java compiler will allow this, because it is a **declaration**) like

```
byte suit = 1;
byte rank = 12;
Card card = new Card(suit, rank);
```

Comment: Yeah, I knew that these work. However, I was interested in the idea behind this limitation. Could you provide some reference I could read about this?

Comment: @SerjArdovic [JLS-3.10. Literals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10)

Answer (score 1):

Elliott is correct @Serj but it is not a limitation. JAVA permits method overloading (methods of the same name but with different parameter both in number and in type) and that is extremely useful. This means you could have another Card constructor of the form Card (int suit, int rank). Because you specified a literal value, and that is by default an integer in this case, the compiler looked for the definition of Card (int, int). It couldn't be found so the compilation failed.